# Azure app service windows container - Uploading file to File share using mount storage error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, windows-container

I have an simple .NET 4.5 mvc app, which performs simple file upload to a directory.

This app has been containerized to windows container and deployed on Azure app service webapp as containers.

It has option to mount Azure files storage as persistent storage volume to the container.

So I have mapped the mount to point the upload directory. The idea is when user upload the file, it will go to Azure Filestorage via the mount volume.

The mount is successful, how ever when trying to upload getting error "The Parameter is Incorrect" from system.IO.

If we inspect the Azure Filestorage from the storage explorer, there is been an empty file being created. Not sure what is going wrong.

```
2020-10-17 02:36:20,959 82924433ms INFO  FileHelper             UpLoadFile             - ToFilePath : C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FileStorage\UserProfileImages\banner-img.jpg
2020-10-17 02:36:20,975 82924449ms ERROR FileHelper             UpLoadFile             - Error in saving file. The parameter is incorrect.

2020-10-17 02:36:20,975 82924449ms ERROR FileHelper             UpLoadFile             - System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
   at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename)
   at ConnecTiQa.Mvc.Helpers.FileHelper.UpLoadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, HttpServerUtilityBase server, String rename, String SaveFilePath) in C:\app\ConnecTiQa.Mvc\Helpers\FileHelper.cs:line 204
```

[Storage account screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4EJV.png)

**Update 1:**

Not only update. Having issue with accessing the file(reading) from the mounted volume as well.

[Mount volume file access error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiCSt.png)

Comment: this is the exact problem I'm having and nothing I've tried has worked... simply using kudu command console and going into the mounted file share and doing a "type filename.txt" shows the same problem "The parameter is incorrect".  Please post if you make any progress.

Comment: I got in contact with Microsoft and they said "This bug has been acknowledged by Product Group and they are currently working on it to resolve as soon as possible. However, there’s no ETA currently as to when the bug will be fixed.".  I've asked for an issue/ticket reference so I can track when it is resolved but haven't heard back yet. So the good news is probably we weren't doing anything wrong, we were just the only 2 people in the world trying this!

Comment: Opened a support ticket on this issue today too. I will forward this info and report back if I get any info back. I can do a "dir" but can not read/write any files.

Answer (score 1):

This was too long to post as a comment. Direct from Microsoft Support:

Hypervisor-isolated containers run inside a lightweight component called a UVM (Utility VM). When a directory from the host is mapped into a hypervisor-isolated Windows container, Hyper-V uses VSMB (virtual SMB) to map the share into the UVM. VSMB supports an optimization called direct map, which reduces memory overhead on the host for the share. As part of supporting direct map, VSMB must be able to query for the file ID of the file being accessed. So in this case VSMB would be querying Azure Files to get the file ID. However, Azure Files currently does not support querying for file ID from its shares, and this is what produces the ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER error that is observed when accessing the share.

There are effectively two issues here:
Azure Files does not support querying for file ID.
I have started a thread with a contact on Azure Files to see if this is something they could support in the future.
When querying for file ID fails, VSMB does not fall back to using a non-direct mapped access to the share
This bug exists in 19H1, 20H1, and 20H2. In RS5 VSMB did not query for file ID, but this was changed in 19H1 to make VSMB more correct, and eliminate other bugs. Post-20H2, this bug has been fixed so that VSMB will fall back to non-direct map if the file ID query fails, but there hasn't been a new version of Windows Server since the bug was fixed. The fix will be available in the next Windows Server release.

But still we have the issue with azure file that does not support querying for file ID and there is no ETA at this point. The Windows team is looking at it  in this case a workaround recommended by our product group is  to use another mechanism like the Azure SDK for .NET for reading/writing files to storage

Comment: Thanks for the update, my understanding is that the problem should be fixed now. Engineers discovered that the issue was produced by a regression introduced in the Windows SAC 20H1 release used by Azure App Service to power Windows Containers. A private fix was rolled out to App Services at end of December 2020, and the private fix will be removed in a few months when a proper fix to Windows is released around the first quarter of 2021.  I don't have a test environment to confirm it's working though.

Answer (score 0):

<del>The problem is that the mount in the Windows container only has the permission RX, see the screenshot here:</del>


<del>You do not have the write permission in the mount point, so you cannot write the content into the files.</del>

**Update:**

I made a mistake and I'm sorry about that. The mount point is the path that you set in the path mappings. For example, if you set the mount path as `/inetpub/wwwroot/filestorage/mnt`, then the mount point is the final folder `mnt`, and all the actions in it would be incorrect:

[image]

I'm not sure if this the issue, but I guess it's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But I have issues with read also. Updated my question with details

Comment: `/inetpub/wwwroot/filestorage/` this is my mount point. if type dir, can see all the existing files listing. but cannot read or write.

Comment: @Singaravelan Yes, that's right. You can see all of them, but you can do nothing to them. That's the problem. The Linux container does not have this problem.

Comment: @CharlesXu can you expand a bit more please - I'm getting the same issue... Windows Container, with Azure Files SMB file share, my app can view the file share folder and the files within it, but can't read the contents or write the contents.  Are you suggesting an incorrect Azure Storage Mount was done, if so can you provide an example with how it should be done correctly? Singara velan if you get it working please post (definitely a permissions issue but trying to figure out why).

Comment: @RobertShattock There is no way for windows container. Maybe it does not support right now. I suggest you can use other services to run windows containers such as AKS.

Comment: @CharlesXu the feature has been in preview since last year and is discussed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-windows ... the commands work to create a share which shows up as C:\myshare etc. but the permissions just seem broken.

Comment: @RobertShattock Yes, the mount is no problem. But permission is a big problem.

Comment: @CharlesXu, I agree, permissions appear to be the problem though interestingly when I try to write to a location outside of the file share I get the error: "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test\dummy2.txt' is denied." but within the file share I get the error: "System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.". Do you have any suggestions to fix since Microsoft say this should work as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?pivots=container-windows.

Comment: @Singaravelan If the answer is helpful to you and please accept it.

Comment: @RobertShattock No, I have no idea about it. Maybe you can feedback on it.

Comment: @CharlesXu RobertShattock, we escalated to one of the Microsoft partners, will see any workaround coming in.